# What happenes during a query using mondrian?

Tags: olap, mondrian

I know mondrian converts MDX queries into relational queries and return the result. But is there any details about this process?

I use the sample cube HR. Here is the MDX:

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    TopCount({[Time].[Time].[Month].Members}, 3, [Measures].[Org Salary])
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Org Salary]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [HR]
```

And  this is the SQL generated by the MDX. I find it in log:

```
select
    "time_by_day"."the_year" as "c0",
    "time_by_day"."quarter" as "c1",
    "time_by_day"."the_month" as "c2",
    "time_by_day"."month_of_year" as "c3",
    sum("salary"."salary_paid") as "c4"
from
    "salary" as "salary",
    "time_by_day" as "time_by_day"
where
    "time_by_day"."the_year" = 1997
and
    "salary"."pay_date" = "time_by_day"."the_date"
group by
    "time_by_day"."the_year",
    "time_by_day"."quarter",
    "time_by_day"."the_month",
    "time_by_day"."month_of_year"
order by
    CASE WHEN sum("salary"."salary_paid") IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, sum("salary"."salary_paid") DESC,
    CASE WHEN "time_by_day"."the_year" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, "time_by_day"."the_year" ASC,
    CASE WHEN "time_by_day"."quarter" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, "time_by_day"."quarter" ASC,
    CASE WHEN "time_by_day"."the_month" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, "time_by_day"."the_month" ASC,
    CASE WHEN "time_by_day"."month_of_year" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, "time_by_day"."month_of_year" ASC
```

**I change top 3 to top 10 and I got the same SQL**. And the SQL has nothing like "limit".

**So I am wondering what happenes during a query?** I searched and didn't get any useful information. Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Longxing

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your Mondrian log you will see infromation about this like:

- SqlMemberSource.getMemberChildren
- SqlTupleReader.readTuples
- SqlStatisticsProvider.getColumnCardinality
- Segment.load

Mondrian is reading the tubles and loading the segments from SQL, letting the database do some of the calculations, and doing the rest internally. Based on your MDX, schema, and setup it will give different tasks to the database and internal calculations, trying to solve it in a performance and memory optimal way. Taking into account that it should have a best possible cache for future queries.

Comment: You mean MDX may have different execution in Mondrian based on MDX, schema and setup. For example, the Mondrian may get all data from database and cache it and apply topCount in Mondrian or just calculate in database. Am I  right?

Comment: @LongxingWei Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I find the configure in mondrian.properties.  mondrian.rolap.aggregates.optimizePredicates=true. That helps. Thanks